# Read all the solutions on this website as well as official solutions

Tags: probability

The question goes like this:

Two bullets are put into a gun's round barrel consecutively, which has a capacity of 6. The gun is shot once, but no bullet is fired. Does rolling the barrel (shuffling) before the next shot increases the probability of firing a bullet?

The answer is that the probability after shuffling is 2/6 and after shooting the empty chamber 1st, probability of shooting a bullet 2nd time is 1/4.

I am unable to understand why it should be 1/4 and not 2/5. Can someone please explain briefly why 2/5 cannot be the answer? I think I don't completely understand how the revolver in the gun works.

I have read all the solutions everywhere but cannot understand why 2/5 is incorrect.

Comment: What have you written down to see why it’s $\frac{1}{4}$ and not $\frac{2}{5}$?

Comment: and why are you certain that $1/4$ is the correct answer? Notice how the probability $2/6>1/4$, does it seem right to you?

Comment: You should give a title that better describes the problem at hand, not one that just declares where you have searched for answers

Comment: @Moko19 sorry sir i am new here that's why.

Answer (score 1):

The bullets are consecutive.  That means that possible arrangements are:

1. 1 and 2
2. 2 and 3
3. 3 and 4
4. 4 and 5
5. 5 and 6
6. 6 and 1

WLOG, we can say that your first shot showed that there was no bullet in chamber 1, and your second shot would come from chamber 2.  This rules out possibilities 1 and 6.  Of the remaining four possibilities, only possibility 2 has a bullet in chamber 2

Comment: Again please mind explaining why 1st and 6th possibility is ruled out. I seem not to understand barrel working. Does the barrel skip the adjacent shot when firing?

Comment: @PRIYANSHUMISHRA: You fired the gun and found there was no bullet in chamber 1.  Both possibilities 1 and 6 had a bullet in chamber 1, and therefore you ruled it out

Comment: ah that's pretty straightforward. Also, can you tell how do I think of this? What's the general strategy?

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider that the bullets were loaded adjacent to each other in a round barrel.

There are 6 ways to arrange the gun with consecutive bullet. If we list the possible scenarios we would get something like this:

(xOOxxx) (xxOOxx) (xxxOOx) (xxxxOO) (OOxxxx) (OxxxxO)

With the first shot being a blank, then we know the last two possibilities are of no use.

Therefore, the 4 possible arrangements of the consecutive bullets, considering the first blank attempt can be seen like this:

(xOOxxx) (xxOOxx) (xxxOOx) (xxxxOO)

Now, looking at the above possibilities, her odds of getting shot are $\frac{1}{4}$ (case: xOOxxx). If you were to re-spin, then there would be 2 bullets remaining and 6 total slots: $\frac{2}{6}$.

Comment: i still don't understand why first and last are of no use. Can you help explain there? When I fire the first time the chamber is empty, the barrel rotates clockwise and the bullet gets shot. Could you help me understand why 2/5 is not correct? Also, how does barrel rotation work?

Answer (score 0):

The sample space was 2-bullets and 4-empty slots.and both the bullets were loaded consecutively i.e in any case the barrel will look like (BEEEEB,BBEEEE,EBBEEEE,EEBBEE,EEEBBE,EEEEBB) SINCE FIRST SHOT WAS EMPTY.
But there are two slots which are 100% safe and 2 slots which are risky i.e (EEB,BEE)
But Spin can only happen one at a time i.e you can spin clockwise and anticlock wise at one time and if you do clockwise one slot becomes safe and other risky same goes for anti clock in any case there will be 3 saft shots and 1 unsafe shot and our sample space also becomes 4 because after 1st shot 3 safe and 1 unsafe shot remain because of rotation of the direction 2nd unsafe shot will never be fired